# shell script ambiguous redirect

Tags: shell, redirect, ambiguous

I am trying to create simple shell script which will identify difference between output of two text files. I am able to successfully run script when I redirect to file (i.e. > a and > b).

What I am trying below is to redirect output to variable instead of file to avoid unnecessary file creation but I am getting error `ambiguous redirect`.

Can someone educate me how to fix this error?

```
    sed -n '/eTopUp MU(55) Gateway Status1:/,/eTopUp MU(60) Gateway Status:/p' /root/scripts/msmscgateway |grep "CIMD2:" | awk '{print $1, $2}' > $a
    sed -n '/eTopUp MU(55) Gateway Status1:/,/eTopUp MU(60) Gateway Status:/p' /root/scripts/last/msmscgatewaylast |grep "CIMD2:" |awk '{print $1, $2}'  > $b
    echo="diff $a $b"

#echo "$DIFF"
```

`test2.sh: line 2: $b: ambiguous redirect`

I have also tried other way but get different error

```
$a=`sed -n '/eTopUp MU(55) Gateway Status1:/,/eTopUp MU(60) Gateway Status:/p' /root/scripts/msmscgateway |grep "CIMD2:" |awk '{print $1, $2}'`
$b=`sed -n '/eTopUp MU(55) Gateway Status1:/,/eTopUp MU(60) Gateway Status:/p' /root/scripts/last/msmscgatewaylast |grep "CIMD2:"|awk '{print $1, $2}'`
echo="diff <$a <$b"
```

`test1.sh: line 1: =CSMSH3: command not found`
`test1.sh: line 2: =CSMSH3: command not found`

But individual commands are working fine when executed from shell prompt

`"sed -n '/eTopUp MU(55) Gateway Status1:/,/eTopUp MU(60) Gateway Status:/p' /root/scripts/msmscgateway |grep "CIMD2:" |awk '{print $1, $2}'"`

also tried below from command prompt but fails in script

diff <(sed -n '/eTopUp MU(55) Gateway Status1:/,/eTopUp MU(60) Gateway Status:/p' /root/scripts/msmscgateway |grep "CIMD2:" |awk '{print $1, $2}') <(sed -n '/eTopUp MU(55) Gateway Status1:/,/eTopUp MU(60) Gateway Status:/p' /root/scripts/last/msmscgatewaylast |grep "CIMD2:" |awk '{print $1, $2}')       get below error test4.sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: diff can take only a file as argument and whet you are trying is comparing 2 strings which wont work

Comment: diff <(sed -n '/eTopUp MU(55) Gateway Status1:/,/eTopUp MU(60) Gateway Status:/p' /root/scripts/msmscgateway |grep "CIMD2:" |awk '{print $1, $2}') <(sed -n '/eTopUp MU(55) Gateway Status1:/,/eTopUp MU(60) Gateway Status:/p' /root/scripts/last/msmscgatewaylast |grep "CIMD2:" |awk '{print $1, $2}')

Comment: diff <(CDM1) <(CMD2) is probably giving you an error because your script is a bourne shell? Try bash instead.

Comment: Don't repeat yourself.  It appears that the only difference between the commands used to generate `$a` and `$b` is the input file. Don't make a reader expend effort to realize that fact.  Refactor the code so it is obvious.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using
[command substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution)

```sh
foo=$(sed 'bar' baz.txt)
```

or
[process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution)

```sh
read foo < <(sed 'bar' baz.txt)
```

or with Bash 4.2 you can use
[`lastpipe`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024)

```sh
shopt -s lastpipe
sed 'bar' baz.txt | read foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Your:

```
sed -n '/eTopUp MU(55) Gateway Status1:/,/eTopUp MU(60) Gateway Status:/p' /root/scripts/msmscgateway |grep "CIMD2:" | awk {print $1, $2}' > $a
sed -n '/eTopUp MU(55) Gateway Status1:/,/eTopUp MU(60) Gateway Status:/p' /root/scripts/last/msmscgatewaylast |grep "CIMD2:" |awk '{print $1, $2}'  > $b
```

should really be:

```
a=$(sed -n '/eTopUp MU(55) Gateway Status1:/,/eTopUp MU(60) Gateway Status:/p' /root/scripts/msmscgateway |grep "CIMD2:" | awk '{print $1, $2}')
b=$(sed -n '/eTopUp MU(55) Gateway Status1:/,/eTopUp MU(60) Gateway Status:/p' /root/scripts/last/msmscgatewaylast |grep "CIMD2:" |awk '{print $1, $2}')
```

To put the output into variables. Right now it probably complains because `$a` and `$b` in your case translates to nothing when it expands.

However as someone mentions, this probably won't work with `diff $a $b`.

Comment: this works from command prompt but fails in script  diff <(sed -n '/eTopUp MU(55) Gateway Status1:/,/eTopUp MU(60) Gateway Status:/p' /root/scripts/msmscgateway |grep "CIMD2:" |awk '{print $1, $2}') <(sed -n '/eTopUp MU(55) Gateway Status1:/,/eTopUp MU(60) Gateway Status:/p' /root/scripts/last/msmscgatewaylast |grep "CIMD2:" |awk '{print $1, $2}')

Comment: It fails in `sh` but works in `bash` because they are different.

Answer (score 0):

No need for variables at all if you don't want to (in Bash at least):

```
diff <(echo -e "a\nb\nc") <(echo -e "a\nc\nc")
```

Basic syntax is

```
diff <(CMD1) <(CMD2)
```

Comment: hi kjell diff <(sed -n '/eTopUp MU(55) Gateway Status1:/,/eTopUp MU(60) Gateway Status:/p' /root/scripts/msmscgateway |grep "CIMD2:" |awk '{print $1, $2}') <(sed -n '/eTopUp MU(55) Gateway Status1:/,/eTopUp MU(60) Gateway Status:/p' /root/scripts/last/msmscgatewaylast |grep "CIMD2:" |awk '{print $1, $2}') is executing fine if i run it thru command prompt but when i run it thru script it flash error "syntax error near unexpected token `('"

Comment: Is your script a bourne script (#!/bin/sh)? Try bash (#!/bin/bash)