# "ambiguous redirectine" while redirecting the output from shell script

Tags: shell

demo.sh has following line:

```
. ./one.sh  > ../Results/myResult.txt 2>&1
```

when i run  ./demo.sh it is giving:

```
ambiguous redirectine 1: 1
```

But the myResult.txt gets created at appropriate location with size 0 KB.

If i remove the redirection of output, it script works fine. What is wrong with my script?
I have gone through [Ambiguous output redirect on solaris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17965871/ambiguous-output-redirect-on-solaris),  [shell script ambiguous redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16008862/shell-script-ambiguous-redirect), [ambiguous redirect - file gets created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18032258/ambiguous-redirect-file-gets-created). Nothing helped though.

Comment: I've tried a similar command, and it works.  What shell are you using?

Comment: I tried it without putting shebang. When I put shebang it is saying   : No such file or directory. I tried it with sh, ksh, bash.

Comment: What are you putting after the shebang?  What's your system default shell?

Comment: I don't know what shell was default. I tried changing the shell by typing bash,sh.  "ps -p $$"  shows accrodingly. My shebang is "#!/bin/sh". I change it when i change the shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're saving your script with DOS-style line endings (CRLF instead of LF), that can produce all of the symptoms you're seeing.

Change the line endings using the text editor or command-line utility of your choice, then try again.